# Access ArrayList of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following data structure:

```
dataModel.training = {ArrayList@4748}  size = 4
    0 = {HashMap@4784}  size = 6
      0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4790} "controller" -> "Training01"
            key = {String@4796} "controller"
            value = {String@4797} "Training01"
      1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4791} "description" -> "0101_0"
      2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4792} "subset" -> "0,62"
      3 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4793} "table" -> "voctrain"
      4 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4794} "template" -> "resthai"
      5 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@4795} "form" -> "Training01"
   1 = {HashMap@4785}  size = 9
   2 = {HashMap@4786}  size = 9
   3 = {HashMap@4787}  size = 7
```

How can I obtain, for example, the value for the key "controller" in the first entry of the ArrayList (dataModel.training[0])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map map =dataModel.training.get(0)// this return Hashmap at 0th Index
map.get("controller");// returns 'training'
```

if you want to do it in a single statement

```
dataModel.training.get(0).get("controller");
```

likewise you can generalize for all other keys and values

hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: You brought me to the right path! But I had to cast, because the return types are objects:
Map map = (Map) dataModel.training.get(0); and 
String controller = (String) map.get("controller");

Thank you!